# Test depth-first tree

Tags: java, unit-testing, tree, depth-first-search

I made a Java program to browse a tree with depth-first. The program is correct, but the choice of the son of a node is random. for example in this tree :

[image]

sometimes, the result is:

- `A-B-E-C-F-D`
- `A-C-F-D-B-E`
- `A-B-E-D-C-F`

I want to make test (unit testing) of this program but i I have no idea, how i can do it? please

I thought to do a List that contains the elements and compare the elements of the list with the result of my depth-first tree, but the result of my depth-first is randomly. Then I can not compare it with the elements of the List.

Comment: Welcome @user1149157. Please use formatting possibilities, browser spelling correction and avoid greetings.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 properties you want to test for:

1. Each node visited exactly one
2. Traversal is depth first

The first is easy to test: the number of unique nodes visited must be equal to the number of nodes in the tree. Can test that against any random tree.

The second is slightly trickier - expressing it in the general case is probably more complex than the tested code. Easier just to pick some representative constraints based on the specific known data, i.e.

- B must be after A
- E must be *immediately* after B
- ...

Hard to conceive of realistic code that satisfies the first property for all trees, but would fail the second only in specific cases. So outside of the most formal of safety critical systems (and what are they doing using dynamic data structures anyway?), that's going to be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't clicked on your link, but if the code is truly random and is intended to be, then you should make your unit test so that it says "given this input, then the output must be one of these three things". This isn't ideal because it might take many, many runs before a bug shows up (i.e. the first few times you run it, it might just randomly mask the bug), but I suspect it's the best you can do for testing an algorithm with random behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the order of the children of each node is not deterministic. You probably used a `Set` to hold children. Consider using a `LinkedHashSet` (which preserves insertion order) or a `SortedSet` (which sorts children). This way, the order will always be the same.

If randomness is a feature of your tree and you want to keep it as is, then see the other answers, or change the algorithm itself to make sure you always sort the children while traversing the tree.

Comment: Thanks about your answer,

but if i use sets, the order is not specify and my depth-first may be wrong and I did not realize my mistake .

Comment: You missed what I meant. The nodes of the tree itself probably use a Set to contain their children. Show us the implementation of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a data set for the unit test that has just a few valid results (it should however have more than one, obviously), and test whether the result is one of them.

Alternatively, you could try to impose a well-defined order on the nodes (e.g. by alphabetically sorting the children of each node, instead of managing them in a `Set`)